# Get Touch Events from Windows for Tablet or Collaboration Display

Tags: c#, winapi, touch, performancecounter

I would like to get global touch events from the operating system similar to the way you get system info using GetSystemInfo from 'kernel32'dll. I am developing a console app that detects the when the screen of the device is touched like a tablet pc or Collaboration Display
.

Comment: Is the system of the touch screen device win10? Is your purpose to calculate the total time touched by the user on the device? Or just monitor whether the user is touching the screen?

Comment: Yes it is Windows 10, and my goal is to just keep a count of the number of times the screen was just. It will be used for some usage analysis. So if the user touches the sceen, it gets notified and increments a counter.

Answer (score 0):

> So if the user touches the screen, it gets notified and increments a
> counter.

[GetLastInputInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo) can be used for touch interaction.

Related: [Detect last interaction (touch) and display confirmation box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521384/c-sharp-win-form-detect-last-interaction-touch-and-display-confirmation-box)

Note: This function will also work for mouse input and keyboard input. But considering that it is a touch screen device, users are more inclined to touch interaction.

Comment: @SteamReal Hi, please tell me if it is useful to you.